# Getting the content of a div in google translate not working

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the content of the div with id `result_box` in [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/how%20to%20play) using simple_html_dom, but it returns nothing. I tried to return another div's content and it worked perfectly. looks like the problem is just with that div.
`result_box` is the div that the translation will appear on.

here is my code

```
$googleSearch="the contente i want to translate";
$googlePage="https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/$googleSearch";

$Chtml = file_get_html($googlePage);
$gt = $Chtml->find('#result_box ',0)->plaintext;
echo '<br>'.$gt.'<br>';
```

What could be the cause? and how can I solve it?
If this can't be done with `simple html dom`, is there any alternative ways to do it?

> Note that I don't want to use Google translate API

Comment: You cannot get this information this way. If you use the debugger in your browser, you will see that the html you get from the https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/$googleSearch URL, returns an empty result_box. The result_box is filled in later from an AJAX call.

Comment: @axxis So I need to find the AJAX call and print it in my php script?

Comment: I guess so. Of course the javascript that google translate uses is compressed, so it won't be that easy. I see in my browser's debugger that after the request for the main page, there is a separate request to: https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=ar&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&source=bh&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=521168|823703&q=$googleSearch and this returns a JSON file with the translation.

Comment: @axxis Thank you for your time and help. If you posted an answer with this I'll accept it  :) , and I'll try to solve the rest of my problem by myself (i now know how to continue).

Answer (score 0):

The `result_box` element does not have any plain text:

```
<div style="zoom:1" dir="ltr">
   <div id="tts_button">
   <span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">
      <span class="hps">spring</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

I don't know what `$Chtml->find('#result_box',0)` is doing, but probably you need to iterate to the next `<span>` and get the text from there

**EDIT**:

Furthermore, I do not know whether the trailing blank on the `Id` would probably prevent `simple_hmtl_dom` from finding anything:

`$Chtml->find('#result_box ',0)` vs. `$Chtml->find('#result_box',0)`

Comment: `$Chtml->find('#result_box ',0)->plaintext` returns all the plain text inside the div `result_box `,and it includes also the plain text inside all the tags that are inside that div.